# Passing cdef class object as argument to cdef method

Tags: python, cython

In Cython, is it possible to pass a Cython cdef class object instance as an argument to a cdef method. For example if we have below class:

```
# foo.pyx
cdef class Foo:
    def __cinit__(self, double arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def get_arg_sqr(self):
        return self.arg * 2

# bar.pyx 
from foo cimport Foo
cdef exec_foo(Foo foo):
    cdef double sqr = foo.get_arg_sqr()
```

How you achieve something like this ?

```
# test.py
from foo import Foo
import bar
Foo f = Foo(2.33)
exec_foo(f)
```

Comment: I have added `cimport foo` to `bar.pyx` thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. IIRC, the idea here is to separate logic and implementation, similar to header files in c. You can create "interface" classes in a `pxd` file and then use `cimport` to write variable declarations like `cdef Foo f`. The actual implementations are then in a `.pyx` file.

Comment: This may interest you: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html

Answer (score 0):

`exec_foo` should be `def` not `cdef` if you want to access it outside your cython code. In the notebook the following seems to work (without pyd/pyx files)

In my opening cell

```
import cython
%load_ext Cython
```

In the next cell:

```
%%cython

cdef class Foo:
    cdef double arg

    def __cinit__(self, double arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def get_arg_sqr(self):
        return self.arg * 2

def exec_foo(Foo foo):
    cdef double sqr = foo.get_arg_sqr()
    return sqr
```

In the final cell.

```
f = Foo(1.0)
exec_foo(f)
```